# <ul> not separating properly

Tags: html, css

I am working on a side navbar for my website and I am having an issue with spacing.

If you will notice in my fiddle the `<ul>` in my `receiptDropDown` does not push the kiosk button down so that it displays properly.

Also, how can I get it so the hover option for the receipt button doesn't show up if I hover over that `<ul>`

The issue was I was setting the height of each `li` thus preventing from each `li` expanding to fit the additional `ul`, when height needed to be set for each `anchor`

**Here's the updated fiddle with solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/CbcSx/6/

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: @Paulie_D and this doesn't? I provided the fiddle and if I knew why it didn't work I wouldn't have posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add margin-top to your #kiosk button's CSS in order to move it down.

```
#kiosk{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -41px -578px; margin-top: 30px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CbcSx/2/

Comment: I know I could do that, but that is not how the `ul` normally works. if you take out the css code and put any information in the first `li`'s you will see that the next element will drop below the preceding `li`

Comment: That's because you're removing the list style from your `li` tags:  `.epsonNav li{margin-top: 5px; list-style: none;}`

Comment: Doesn't do anything, and taking away the `list-style` shouldn't do anything aside from removing the bullets... check my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CbcSx/4/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're missing here... the list style removes the bullets. The `li` inside of the receipt tab is being dropped down and indented in like it's supposed to be. Adding height to your li values and and making them relative is going to change how lists inside of lists are displayed. If you want the list inside of your list to have a different height/width as well then you need to tell CSS to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/CbcSx/8/